# How to show the following matrix is positive definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How to show the following matrix is positive definite.
\begin{equation}
 \sum_{i=1}^n \Big[(d_i^Tp)^2\left\{\left(
 \begin{array}{c}
   d_i\\
   A_ip
 \end{array}
\right)
\left(
 \begin{array}{c}
   d_i\\
   A_ip
 \end{array}
\right)^T
- (d_i^Tp)
\left(
 \begin{array}{cc}
   0 & A_i^T\\
    A_i&0
 \end{array}
\right)
\right\}\Big],  
\end{equation}
where $A_i$ is a $k\times m$ matrix which has at least non-zero element in one row or column and at most one non-zero element in other rows, $p$ and $d_i$ are $m\times 1$ vectors with $p_j \in (0,1)$ for all $j=1,\ldots,m$, $p^T{\bf 1}=1$ and only one non-zero element in $d_i$.

Comment: I couldn't show positive definiteness of each term in that summation. One may be able to write the above as a quadratic form and then can say it is positive definite.

Comment: I guess the right way to do it is induction because if n grows it becomes very difficult to handle.

Comment: in fact the things which I tried was the probability of this to be positive definite is going to 1 when $n$ is large enough.

Comment: Dear Luis, as I mentioned in my first comment, it won't be true for n=1 always

Comment: I write the above as: $$
\left(
 \begin{array}{c}
   J^T\\
    {\bf 0}
 \end{array}
\right) \left(
 \begin{array}{c}
   J\\
    {\bf 0}
 \end{array}
\right)^T+\left(
 \begin{array}{c}
   {\bf 0}\\
   Z^T
 \end{array}
\right)
\left(
 \begin{array}{c}
   {\bf 0}\\
   Z
 \end{array}
\right)^T-\left(
 \begin{array}{c}
   J^TD_1\\
    Z^TD2
 \end{array}
\right)\left(
 \begin{array}{c}
   D_1^TJ\\
    D_2^TZ
 \end{array}
\right)^T+\left(
 \begin{array}{c}
   J^TB^T\\
    Z^Tp^T
 \end{array}
\right)\left(
 \begin{array}{c}
   BJ\\
    pZ
 \end{array}
\right)^T,
$$
when $D_1D_1^T=I$ and $D_2D_2^T=I$.

Comment: I have the summation as a quadratic form but with one negative sign. Can it help to show it's positive?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot, because it is not always positive definite. Counterexample: with $n=1$ (i.e. there is only one summand), $d_1=\pmatrix{1\\ 1},\,p=\frac12d_1$ and $A_1=\pmatrix{2&1\\ 1&1}$, the resulting matrix in the pair of the curly braces is
$$
B_1=\pmatrix{1&1&-\frac12&0\\ 1&1&\frac12&0\\ -\frac12&\frac12&\frac94&\frac32\\ 0&0&\frac32&1}.
$$
$B_1$ is real symmetric, but when $x=(1,-1,1,-1)^T$, we have $x^TB_1x=-\frac74<0$. Hence $B_1$ is not even positive semidefinite.

By perturbing $A_1$ by a little, we can also get an infinity family of distinct matrices $B_1,\,B_2,\,\ldots$ such that for the aforementioned vector $x$, each $x^TB_ix$ is negative. Hence we can obtain a counterexample for an arbitrary $n$.

Comment: You are correct, but $A_i$ in my problem is in such a way that there is atleast one non-zero element in each row or columns. Thank you for reminding me to edit the question.

Comment: Moreover I mentioned that it is not possible to show for each term and your example is when n=1

Comment: @Sedi Nothing changes even if $n\ne 1$ and each $A_i$ is entrywise nonzero. See my new edit.

Comment: Dear user1551, Thank you for the answer, Ur answer for earlier question is correct. But I realized in my case $d_i$ vector has only one non-zero element and $n$ goes to infinity.

Comment: Dear user1551, I am trying to write it as quadratic form, as I have mentioned above, but I have one negative sign.

Comment: @Sedi What do you mean? As shown in my answer, the quadratic form is *not* always positive definite. There are at least one counterexamples for every $n$.

Comment: I understood your answer, thank you for that. I was trying to find some conditions which give the positive definiteness.